# delete with 2 join get error - mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this delete query in MYSQL (via phpMyAdmin) ANd I keep  getting this error :

```
DELETE
p,pm 
from wp_posts p
inner join wp_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.id in (SELECT  MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts inner join wp_postmeta on (wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id and  meta_key = 'old_id')
      WHERE post_type = 'post'
      GROUP BY meta_value
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1)
```

any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your code
You don't should use as in subselect for IN clause

```
DELETE p, pm 
from wp_posts as p
inner join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.id in (SELECT  MIN( id ) 
      FROM wp_posts 
      inner join wp_postmeta on (wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
                                  and  meta_key = 'old_id')
      WHERE post_type = 'post'
      GROUP BY meta_value
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1)
```

Comment: i still get : You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause

Comment: `DELETE
p,pm 
from wp_posts p
inner join wp_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.id
where p.id in (SELECT  MIN( id ) 
      FROM wp_posts inner join wp_postmeta on (wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id and  meta_key = 'old_id')
      WHERE post_type = 'post'
      GROUP BY meta_value
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1)` this is my query

Comment: Answer  updated ..but please show me the exact  error you have

Comment: `2 errors were found during analysis.
Unexpected keyword. (near "inner join" at position 36)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "inner join" at position 36)` and `You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: this is not a sql error .. but your testing tool? .. anyway answer updated adding as for table alias